# Stream API. Метод reduce()

Tags: java, java-stream

Вопрос касательно третьей формы метода:

```
U reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)
```

Не могу понять за что отвечает третий параметр. Есть простой пример:

```
Stream<Phone> phoneStream = Stream.of(new Phone("iPhone 6 S", 54000),
                                      new Phone("Lumia 950", 45000),
                                      new Phone("Samsung Galaxy S 6", 40000),
                                      new Phone("LG G 4", 32000));

int sum = phoneStream.reduce(0,
                             (x, y) -> {
                                 if (y.getPrice() < 50000)
                                     return x + y.getPrice();
                                 else
                                     return x + 0;
                             },
                             (x, y) -> x + y);
System.out.println(sum); // 117000
```

Прогнал дебагером - третий параметр даже не используется. В источнике написано довольно непонятное объяснение "Третий параметр представляет бинарную операцию, которая суммирует все промежуточные вычисления.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, эта перегруженная форма полезна тогда, когда нужна двухэтапная свёртка с изменением типа результата. Попробуйте сделать так без combiner'а:

```
Stream.of("a", "bb", "ccc") 
      .reduce(0, (acc, s) -> acc + s.length());
```

Не выйдет. А так - легко

```
Stream.of("a", "bb", "ccc") 
      .reduce(0, (acc, s) -> acc + s.length(), (l, r) -> l + r);
```

Но особенно такая форма полезна, когда у вас стрим параллельный. В разных потоках будет запущено несколько экземпляров функции-аккумулятора, а потом в главном потоке их результаты будут объединены комбайнером.